# Bot framework composer not detecting .Net core on Mac OS M1

Tags: .net-core

I installed .Net core in my Mac OS M1 Pro, but Bot Framework Composer not detecting .Net core and while creating app, it keeps complaining about .Net core needed.

dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.425 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk]

dotnet --version
3.1.425

Please help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance..

I tried reinstall .Net core but it didn't help..

I also tried setting path, but it didn't help